# Contenteditable DOM updates incorrectly when array changes. Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, contenteditable

I've created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4WQy6uO9HnBfuhsJQZoI?p=preview).

The code is here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="changeArrayToOne()">ChangeOne</button>
      <button (click)="changeArrayToTwo()">ChangeTwo</button>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let c0 of array" contenteditable='true'>
                {{c0}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  `,
})
 export class App {
  name:string;
  initial = [];
  one = [];
  two = [];
  array = [];
  constructor() {
    this.initial = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    this.one = [4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    this.two = [4,4,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    this.array = this.initial.slice();
  }

  changeArrayToOne() {
    this.array = this.one.slice();
  }

  changeArrayToTwo() {
    this.array = this.two.slice();
  }
}
```

`

I'm trying to create **editable** table that is populated by array with `ngFor`. I use `contenteditable='true'` attribute for that.

Table is being populated with `this.array` variable.
I also have two buttons `ChangeOne` and `ChangeTwo`, which replace all values of `this.array` with values from arrays `this.one` and `this.two`.

So, here are steps to reproduce the problem:

- Run the plunker (table is populated with values of `this.initial`
  array).
- The first element in the table row is `0`. Change it to `10` (remember, table is editable).
- Press the button `ChangeOne`. It will replace `this.array` values from `this.initial` to `this.one`.

As you can see, the first three elements were replaced with `4`'s and the `10` has moved to the fourth position.
If you'll press `ChangeTwo` or `ChangeOne` again, the `10` will just move to the right.

**Why?!** And how can it be fixed? I don't want `10` to be present at all after I replace the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hPc8NGXbC9wWVZ0LH5es?p=preview)** to show how it works. The code to use is this :

```
customTrackBy(index, item) {
  return index + '-' + item;
}
```

HTML :

```
*ngFor="let c0 of array; trackBy: customTrackBy"
```

Because you array is made of **primtive values**, you have to tell Angular how to check for changes. Since the value changes, you have to return the item, and if you have an issue with the index, you have to return the index too.

See this as a custom way of creating IDs for your array.

Comment: Thank you, it fixes it! But if I change, for example, 10-th element of the initial array, and then switch the arrays, the changed element will still be there. Why?

Comment: That's an excellent question, this should not ... Maybe you would have more answers on the github of Angular !